# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier: import type

Tags: react-native

I am working on an app and just added `react-native-tags-input` and got this following error once I added `TagInput`:

```
  /Users/robavery/repositories/Spoke/node_modules/react-native-tag-input/index.js:3
  import type {
         ^^^^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
      at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
      at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
      at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
      at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
      at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/robavery/repositories/Spoke/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
  [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Not sure what `import type` is and how it's used. Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "spoke",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "description": "Spoke",
  "main": "src/server",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.3 <11",
    "npm": "3.10.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --runInBand --forceExit --detectOpenHandles",
    "test-cache": "REDIS_FAKE=1 jest --runInBand --forceExit --detectOpenHandles",
    "test-e2e": "jest --runInBand --config jest.config.e2e.js",
    "test-sqlite": "jest --runInBand --config jest.config.sqlite.js",
    "test-coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "test-coverage-bothbackends": "jest --runInBand --config jest.config.sqlite.js -- __test__/backend.test.js &&  jest --coverage",
    "knex": "knex --knexfile ./knexfile.env.js",
    "clean": "rm -rf $OUTPUT_DIR",
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext js --ext jsx src",
    "prod-build-client": "webpack --config ./webpack/config.js",
    "prod-build-server": "babel ./src -d ./build/server --source-maps --copy-files",
    "prod-build": "npm run clean && npm run prod-build-client && npm run prod-build-server",
    "prod-static-upload": "if [ \"$S3_STATIC_PATH\" != \"\" ] ; then s3cmd sync --acl-public --guess-mime-type ./build/client/assets/ $S3_STATIC_PATH ; fi",
    "postinstall": "if [ \"$NODE_ENV\" = production ] ; then npm run prod-build && npm run prod-static-upload && npm run notify-slack; fi",
    "notify-slack": "if [ \"$SLACK_NOTIFY_URL\" != \"\" ] ; then echo notifying slack && curl -XPOST -d '{\"channel\": \"#spoke\", \"text\":\"'\"$(whoami) building spoke $(git log -1 --pretty=%h) for $AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME\"'\"}' $SLACK_NOTIFY_URL; fi",
    "start": "node ./build/server/server",
    "start:heroku": "BASE_URL=$(node ./build/server/heroku/print-base-url) npm start",
    "dev-message-sender-01": "nodemon -e js,jsx -w ./src --exec ./dev-tools/babel-run -- ./src/workers/message-sender-01",
    "prod-message-sender-01": "./dev-tools/babel-run ./src/workers/message-sender-01.js",
    "dev-message-sender-234": "nodemon -e js,jsx -w ./src --exec ./dev-tools/babel-run -- ./src/workers/message-sender-234",
    "prod-message-sender-234": "./dev-tools/babel-run ./src/workers/message-sender-234.js",
    "dev-message-sender-56": "nodemon -e js,jsx -w ./src --exec ./dev-tools/babel-run -- ./src/workers/message-sender-56",
    "prod-message-sender-56": "./dev-tools/babel-run ./src/workers/message-sender-56.js",
    "dev-message-sender-789": "nodemon -e js,jsx -w ./src --exec ./dev-tools/babel-run -- ./src/workers/message-sender-789",
    "prod-message-sender-789": "./dev-tools/babel-run ./src/workers/message-sender-789.js",
    "dev-job-handler": "nodemon -e js,jsx -w ./src --exec ./dev-tools/babel-run -- ./src/workers/job-handler",
    "prod-job-handler": "./dev-tools/babel-run ./src/workers/job-handler",
    "dev-incoming-message-handler": "nodemon -e js,jsx -w ./src --exec ./dev-tools/babel-run -- ./src/workers/incoming-message-handler",
    "prod-incoming-message-handler": "./dev-tools/babel-run ./src/workers/incoming-message-handler.js",
    "predev-start": "npm run clean",
    "dev-start": "nodemon -e js,jsx,md,mustache -w ./src --exec ./dev-tools/babel-run -- ./src/server",
    "dev-start-debug": "nodemon -e js,jsx,md,mustache -w ./src --exec ./dev-tools/babel-run-debug  -- ./src/server",
    "generate-contacts": "./dev-tools/babel-run ./dev-tools/generate-contacts.js",
    "jest-test": "jest __test__/backend.test.js",
    "dev": "nf start -w --procfile ./dev-tools/Procfile.dev",
    "dev-nowrap": "nf start --trim 500 --procfile ./dev-tools/Procfile.dev --env ./__test__/e2e/.env.e2e",
    "debug-server": "nf start -w --procfile ./dev-tools/Procfile-debug-server.dev"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/MoveOnOrg/spoke.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "spoke",
    "sms",
    "texting",
    "campaigns",
    "campaigning",
    "politics",
    "activism",
    "organizing",
    "field"
  ],
  "author": "Axle Factory",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/MoveOnOrg/Spoke/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/MoveOnOrg/Spoke/#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "aphrodite": "^0.4.1",
    "apollo-client": "^0.4.7",
    "apollo-server-express": "^1.2.0",
    "auth0-js": "^9.10.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.6.3",
    "aws-serverless-express": "https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-serverless-express/-/aws-serverless-express-3.0.2.tgz",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "camelcase-keys": "^4.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^1.1.1",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "dataloader": "^1.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.7.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "faker": "^3.1.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.2",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^1.0.25",
    "googleapis": "^39.2.0",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "graphql-date": "^1.0.3",
    "graphql-tag": "^0.1.9",
    "graphql-tools": "^2.8.0",
    "graphql-type-json": "^0.1.4",
    "humps": "^1.1.0",
    "is-url": "^1.2.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jest-each": "^0.3.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "knex": "^0.17.3",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.16.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.1",
    "material-ui-color-picker": "^1.0.1",
    "material-ui-datatables": "^0.18.2",
    "minilog": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "nexmo": "^1.0.0-beta-7",
    "nodemailer": "^4.3.1",
    "papaparse": "^4.3.6",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-auth0": "^0.6.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-authenticate": "^1.2.0",
    "pg": "^6.4.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "query-string": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.2.1",
    "react-apollo": "^0.3.15",
    "react-async-script": "^0.6.0",
    "react-chartjs": "^0.7.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-formal": "^0.18.5",
    "react-native-tag-input": "^0.0.21",
    "react-router": "^2.5.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "rethink-knex-adapter": "^0.4.18",
    "rollbar": "^0.6.2",
    "thinky": "^2.3.3",
    "timezonecomplete": "^5.5.0",
    "twilio": "^2.11.0",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "wait-for-expect": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.24.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-jest": "^22.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.0.5",
    "eslint": "2.13.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.10.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.5.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.2.2",
    "fakeredis": "^2.0.0",
    "foreman": "^1.4.1",
    "json2csv": "^3.6.2",
    "mockdate": "^2.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.2",
    "prettier": "1.13.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "15",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.10.5",
    "saucelabs": "^1.5.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^3.6.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.0",
    "wait-on": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  }
}
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: The **first** post in #react-native-tags-input

Comment: 2 things: 1st that library appears to be unmaintained (last commit was over a year ago although a contributor appears to still be responding on issue threads). 2nd it's got uncommented, uncompiled flow typings, which is why you're getting an error.

Comment: @JaredSmith what is uncompiled flow typing?

Comment: Flow is an optional type system for Javascript put out by Facebook (kind of an alternative to Microsoft's Typescript). The code needs to be run through the flow typechecker to put out usable Javascript. The authors seem to assume that users will be using flow in their project, which is... not a very good bet on their part unless they just wrote it for themselves.